# Refer Chrome Permission from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to verify whether 'Automatic Downloads' are enabled in the browser. If not I want to show a popup to enable.

How to refer Chrome permission settings from JavaScript to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you research your question? Post your attemps and people are more likely to help you.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this is exposed

Comment: `window.chrome` is available in JavaScript, but filelds defined are not known. I went through Chrome permissions declared [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions), but automatic download flag was not discussed.